# Virtual Hosts Laravel - I need URL addres with name of my aplication

Tags: laravel-5, virtualhost, remote-desktop

I made a virtual host on the remote server and it works, but I would like to include the name of the app in the url address...

example: 10.10.20.30 - work, the homepage of the app opens, but 10.10.20.30/e-lab don't work...

These are my files for a virtual host:

httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/e-lab/public"
ServerName e-lab.test

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/e-lab/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
       Require all granted
</Directory>
```

hosts

```
 127.0.0.1          localhost
 127.0.0.1          e-lab.test
```

and htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ / [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Thanks! ;)

Comment: You cant just create a new directory in your root folder call `/e-lab` and put your application there?

Comment: @fyroc there is already such a folder there .. The problem is that it is set to 10.10.10.50 start page instead of 10.10.10.50/e-lab? : /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem ... In the localhost links works ok, example: `<a href=/login>` , but over the remote server this slash line deletes the folder name (name of aplication), so i put it all links `{{url('something')}}` and now it's ok ... thanks anyway ;) –